# Creating an icon for an iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode

Im sure I've used an apple program for creating icons before, but cant for the life of me remember the  name? I also think that it is not included in the latest Xcode in ML. If so Can you suggest a good free app to use for icon creation?

Answer (score 3):

You are probably looking for the **Icon Composer** tool that used to be bundled as part of Xcode.  When Xcode moved to the App Store a number of utilities and tools were removed from the download bundle.

However, these tools are still available for download.

In Xcode, open the menu: `Xcode -> Open Developer Tools -> More Developer Tools`. This will take you to the Apple Developer website where you can download a number of packages.

### Xcode 8

For Xcode 8, you will find **Icon Composer** (along with a number of other tools) in the **Additional Tools for Xcode** package.

### Prior to Xcode 8

Prior to Xcode 8 **Icon Composer** is included in the **Graphics Tools for Xcode** package.

Comment: Icon Composer is now part of the Additional Tools for Xcode

Comment: @Manquer I've updated the answer to include this change.

Answer (score 1):

GIMP (GNU Image Manipulation Program) is an image retouching and editing tool and is released under the GPLv3 (or later) license as free and open-source software. There are versions of GIMP tailored for most operating systems including Microsoft Windows, Mac OS X and Linux.

GIMP provides all you need, maybe more than that!! Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I have had trouble installing GIMP on ML have you managed to do this?

Comment: Which version have you install? Try this : http://gimp.lisanet.de/Website/Download.html